# Why I'm getting infinite loop in my code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to count all the cycle length of Collatz Conzecture of a range (exp: start=1 and end=5) given by user but my loop is not running perfectly in my code.

here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,count=1;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
        count=1;
        int a=0;
        for(a=i;a<=j;a++)
        {
           while(a>1)
           {
               if(a%2!=0)
               {
                   a=3*a+1;
               }
               else
               {
                   a=a/2;
               }
               count++;
           }
           printf("%d\n",count);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool. You have disproven the conjecture.

Comment: What do you expect when you have `while(1)`?

Comment: *but my loop is not running perfectly in my code*.... what does that mean?

Comment: Thou shalt not alter the loop variable inside the loop, nor modify a collection while iterating over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses `a` as a loop counter in `fora=i;a<=j;a++)` and uses `a` as a value in the computed sequence when it sets `a=3*a+1` or `a=a/2`. When the loop for the sequence ends (due to `while(a>1)`), `a` has the value one. So it never reaches `j` in the `for` loop.

Use different objects for different purposes. Inside the `for` loop, set a different object to `a`, such as `int b = a;`, and use `b` to evaluate the sequence.

You will also want to reset `count` to one before each trial.

Comment: In other words (*cough*) use more descriptive variable names.